# Pull from master or pip install to upgrade?

Tags: git, github, pip

I'm working on a local branch off the master of a Github repo. I initially installed the repo with `pip install <repo_name>`, which gave me version 0.7.0. Now the repo is at version 0.8.0. To update my local branch to the new version can I just do `git pull origin master` or do I need to do `pip install <repo_name> --upgrade`?

My `git remote -v`:

```
origin  git@github.com:repo_name.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:my_name/repo_name.git (push)
```

Comment: `git pull` will generally work if you installed by `pip install -e /path/to/repo`. If you did not install in develop mode, you have to use `pip install /path/to/repo` after every update. Note that this only works for pure python packages. If you have compiled extension modules, things are more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--upgrade` command did not work properly; it's likely another version of the repo was installed at path that was taking priority. So I ran

```
pip uninstall <repo_name>
pip install <repo_name> --user
```

And to confirm I have the correct version I ran

```
python
>>> import <repo_name>
>>> from pkg_resources import get_distribution
>>> get_distribution('<repo_name>').version
>>> '0.8.0'
```

Alternatively one may check the version w/ `<repo_name>.__version__`, but this only works if `version` is an attr of the package, which is not required.